# To or for in this context?

Tags: prepositions

I'm just asking to make sure. Which one is correct?

1. The idea arose to me.
2. The idea arose for me.

Comment: The idea arose *in* me ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the sentences you suggest is natural: the verb **[arise](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/arise)** cannot be used in this way. The best way to express this would be to use a different verb:

> The idea came to me
>   The idea occurred to me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid your sentences seem a little off.

**"Idea arise"** is usually followed by prepositions such as: **from** or **in**, and an event rather than one's self.

here are a couple of examples:

> The idea arose from her husband's newest business venture: arranging
>   customized safaris. [[source]](http://travel.nytimes.com/2006/10/01/realestate/01wczo.html)
>
> The idea arose from a method used by Matthew LeBreton to preserve dead
>   snakes. [[source]](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2010/12/20/the-doomsday-strain)
>
> Ms. Kindell said the idea arose in the interest of helping groups defend themselves at audits. [[source]](http://www.nytimes.com/2001/02/12/business/technology-charities-find-a-gray-area-on-the-net.html)
>
> The idea arose after Carey drivers made hundreds of trips for people stranded by the Sept. 11 attacks. [[source]](https://www.theguardian.com/culture/2015/jun/05/bill-drummond-what-do-i-want-to-go-to-australia-for-anyway)

Therefore, I suggest using these instead:

> I **came up** with the idea.
>
> The idea **popped up in my head**.
>
> The idea **formed** / **emerged** in my mind.
>
> The idea **flashed into** my mind.
>
> The idea **hit** me.

Comment: So, if I’m reading this right, “The idea arose in my head” would be okay, too, especially if additional context explains what prompted the idea.

Comment: @J.R. No, I don't think it would. As I've explained above, it seems really off to use something like "my mind / head". take a look at the examples. here is more: "The idea arose in response to people's need of drinkable water"